# C# Combo Box not display items

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am attempting to have this code display the options of "miles to Kilometers, kilometers to miles, feet to meters, meters to feet, and so on" but upon form loading the combo box is empty. What am I missing? This is coded in C# in Visual Studio.

The data I am trying to pull into the combo box is under conversionTable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Conversions
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int k;
        string[,] conversionTable = {
{"Miles to kilometers", "Miles", "Kilometers", "1.6093"},
{"Kilometers to miles", "Kilometers", "Miles", "0.6214"},
{"Feet to meters", "Feet", "Meters", "0.3048"},
{"Meters to feet", "Meters", "Feet", "3.2808"},
{"Inches to centimeters", "Inches", "Centimeters", "2.54"},
{"Centimeters to inches", "Centimeters", "Inches", "0.3937"}
};

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cboConversions.Items.Add(conversionTable[0, 0]);
            cboConversions.Items.Add(conversionTable[1, 0]);
            cboConversions.Items.Add(conversionTable[2, 0]);
            cboConversions.Items.Add(conversionTable[3, 0]);
            cboConversions.Items.Add(conversionTable[4, 0]);
            cboConversions.Items.Add(conversionTable[5, 0]);
            cboConversions.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void cboConversions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtLength.Clear();
            k = cboConversions.SelectedIndex;
            lblFromLength.Text = conversionTable[k, 1]; // to change the label depending upon user selection
            lblToLength.Text = conversionTable[k, 2];// to change the label depending upon user selection
            txtLength.Focus(); //focus on txtLength

        }


        public bool IsDecimal(TextBox textBox, string name)
        {
            try
            {
                Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a decimal number.", "Entry Error");
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool p = IsDecimal(txtLength, "length"); //decimal check
            if (p == true)
            {
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(txtLength.Text);
                double unit = Convert.ToDouble(conversionTable[k, 3]);
                double ans = a * unit;
                lblCalculatedLength.Text = ans.ToString(); // final conversion display
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the form

[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtJbl.png)

Comment: Your code works just fine here ! - Are you sure the 2 events are actually hooked up? (i.e do they show up in the Form and the cbox's events pane???)

Comment: Should be something else not showed here. Like a DataSource assigned somewhere.

Comment: I’m not too familiar with C# so I am not entirely sure if it is hooked up or not. Is there a property that I need to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar issue.

The reason why the combo box was not populating for me was because the Load property was not assigned in the Form Designer view. I fixed it by clicking on the form, finding the load property and assigning it to `Form1_Load`.